# install google chrome in fedora 23

Tags: google-chrome, fedora-23, dnf

I'm trying to install google-chrome on fedora 23. I have followed this page:
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/73302/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-fedora/
And this is error i get:

```
Error: nothing provides libssl3.so(NSS_3.28)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.167-1.x86_64
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when trying to update google-chrome-stable with --allowerasing, both from google-chrome repo and .rpm downloaded from their website. What I don't get is why dnf can't find libssl3.so when it's located in /usr/lib and /usr/lib64.

Comment: After a lot of research, I installed fedora 27.